# How is it that two objects are created when using the String constructor in java

Tags: java

I was reading this SCJP-Kathy sierra book(from which question originates) and i am quoting from that book page 432

Creating New Strings

```
 Earlier we promised to talk more about the subtle differences between the various
    methods of creating a String. Let's look at a couple of examples of how a String
    might be created, and let's further assume that no other String objects exist in the
    pool:
    String s = "abc"; // creates one String object and one
    // reference variable
    In this simple case, "abc" will go in the pool and s will refer to it.
    String s = new String("abc"); // creates two objects,                   Line X
    // and one reference variable
    In this case, because we used the new keyword, Java will create a new String object
    in normal (nonpool) memory, and s will refer to it. In addition, the literal "abc" will
    be placed in the pool.
```

why does it says in line X (in comments) that it creates two objects

Comment: Did you read the previous parts and well understood them?

Comment: SO is not your personal programming teacher.

Comment: It creates the literal "abc" (not really an object though...), and then creates a String object using that literal. I think it's a bit confusing to call that the creation of 2 objects, though.

Comment: @Renan  then what it is . If you know you could answer otherwise step aside ....donot get bossy here

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes i know previous parts well its just that i want to confirm if two objects are created or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
String s = new String("asdf");
```

and `"asdf"` was not referenced anywhere else then it creates two objects. One is `"asdf"` inside the String Pool in perm gen area and one is `new String("asdf")` which is in the normal heap.

Comment: but i know that objects remain on heap and string pool only references those objects.